# ccmake on vitualbox - “window is too small. a size of at least 65*6 is required to run ccmake”

Tags: virtualbox, cmake

I am trying to run ccmake GUI on Ubuntu 18.04 (virtualbox 6.1 on Windows 10).

However, such error appeared: "window is too small. a size of at least 65*6 is required to run ccmake".

Any hint how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Which terminal emulator program are you using? what is the output of `echo $COLUMNS x $LINES`?

Comment: @steeldriver I am using the default ubuntu terminal. Output is 59*24.

Comment: OK and you can't maximize it beyond that because of the virtualbox display size / resolution... ?

Comment: @steeldriver Oh after I change it problem goes away. I thought it was some other reason.